# how to launch node app automatically in angular 2?

Tags: angular

> I am beginner in learning angular2.
>   I don't know how to launch node app
>   automatically.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It might be helpful [githublink](https://github.com/thangavel28/studentlogin)

Comment: pls post more details like the nodejs main file name eg: `server.js`, your current `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

make use of npm scripts in your package.json file to do any task.

Comment: Sir, can it run automatically without 'npm start'?

Comment: we need some place from where we can start our project so package.json the starting place to trigger the application.Like how application will know that you have triggered any task.if you need any clarity we can have discussion in chat.